# Returning position of int

Tags: c++

The task is to return the leftmost position of given int A in larger int B (counting from 0)

A = 53, B = 1953786, 
return: 2

I've found similar problem, but in that solution java function "indexOf" was used, is there a possibility to do it in other way?

Comment: This, as most questions which give the strong impression of being a blind homework dump, is too braod to be answered. At least please define a coding frame by providing a program which has some sample data in  suitable datastructures and produces an (possibly incorrect) output of the desired shape. Consider stating that you would appreciate help according to the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Are you supposed to do this in C AND in C++? Or with code which can be compiled by both compilers? Are you supposed to stay within integers? Or can you interpret the input as different datatypes, especially strings?

Comment: Sorry, that was my 1st question on Stack, I wasn't expecting a ready complete code, any good tips about methodology would be just fine. It's not said that I can't interpret the input as another datatype, so I think it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to convert them both to `std::string`, and then you can use functions of `std::string` to find the index, similar to how you'd have `indexOf` for Java.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int a = 53;
    int b = 513953786;
    std::string number = std::to_string(b);
    std::string numberToFind = std::to_string(a);
    auto index = number.find(numberToFind);
    std::cout << index;
}
```

This will return `4`, since I moved the `53` to be at the 4th index to show it won't find the earlier `5` or `3` I added, per the advice of @Blastfurnace in the comments

Comment: `find_first_of()` will search for __any one of the characters__ in the given string. I think the OP wants to search for the whole substring and should use `find()` instead.

Comment: Hey wow thanks for the feedback, I don't think I ever knew that! I've updated the answer to be more accurate

Answer (score 0):

What about using the c++ function: [std::find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)? You could then do something like this:

```
int getIndex(int a, int b){
      std::string a_str = std::to_string(a);
      std::string b_str = std::to_string(b);
      return a_str.find(b_str);
}
```

Comment: `find` returns a `size_t` and will return `std::string::npos` if the string is not found, so your function would ideally also return `size_t`